# Framerate plummets when moving or editing objects

Tags: edit-mode, performance, object-mode

Blender community,

I am suddenly encountering a serious problem when using Blender.  When I am simply looking around the scene, Blender runs just fine, at around 60fps.  However, when I am either editing an object, or just moving an object around, it drops to as low as 1.5fps.  I have not encountered this problem before, especially not to anywhere near this degree.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using any vertex groups by any chance?

Comment: No, I am not using vertex groups.  It's just suddenly happening with all my projects.  EDIT: No, it's just happening with a single project.

Comment: Ok, it only happens with these two specific objects, and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.  They are NOT dense in polygons.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the root of the problem, it's the collection the object is in.  Moving any object in the collection causes lag.